# Jetpack Compose App Navigation wont redirect to another page?

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

```
@Composable
fun MainLayout(viewModel: GoalsViewModel){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "Home",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        composable("Home"){
            BodyContent(navController)
        }
        composable("Goals"){
            GoalScreen(viewModel, navController)
        }
        composable("ViewGoals"){
            ViewGoalsScreen(viewModel)
        }
        composable("Fitness"){
            FitnessForm()
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopNavBar()
        }
    ){
        BodyContent(navController)
    }

}
```

Why will the button on my homepage just not do anything? It will println from the composable function its calling but wont redirect or do anything

Comment: what's the code of your `BodyContent`?

Comment: Ok so you are missing quite a few things here. What is the Button on Homescreen? Where exactly are you using the navController? Why do you have scaffold and a NavHost implemented like that?

Comment: Have a look at [the navigation codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your NavHost to the body of your Scaffold:

```
@Composable
fun MainLayout(viewModel: GoalsViewModel){
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopNavBar()
        }
    ){
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "Home",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            composable("Home"){
                BodyContent(navController)
            }
            composable("Goals"){
                GoalScreen(viewModel, navController)
            }
            composable("ViewGoals"){
                ViewGoalsScreen(viewModel)
            }
            composable("Fitness"){
                FitnessForm()
            }
        }
    }
}
```